# How to click a button inside a frame using python, selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on the "Edit" button in the Facebook "Change password" security settings through Python.

```
 # logs in to facebook
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/webdriver')

    # Navigate to Facebook
    browser.get("http://www.facebook.com")

    browser.maximize_window()

    # Search & Enter the Email or Phone field & Enter Password
    username = browser.find_element_by_id("email")
    username.send_keys("email@gmail.com")
    password = browser.find_element_by_id('pass')
    password.send_keys('password')
    submit = browser.find_element_by_name('login')
    submit.click()
    print("logged in")
    time.sleep(5)

    # navigates to security
    browser.get("http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security")
    time.sleep(3)
```

I'm completely new at this, but this code so far runs, and logs into the facebook page, and goes to the security settings. I can't figure out how to click the button, however. Using Inspect, I wasn't able to find an ID and after a lot of googling, I think it may be an issue concerning Frames? Any advice would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    browser.get("http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security")
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security')]")))
    WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[.//span[text()='Change password']]//following-sibling::td[1]/button"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)